# SVG loads but id is empty array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I have my SVG embetted in HTML

```
<object onclick='showStreet()' id="svg-object" data="svg/hamburg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width: 300px"></object>
```

I tried with JS and ended up with jQuery .ready to be sure, I load svg before executing JS on it. Also, I put my script in the beginning of the page, so it "loads" before svg does. But nothing helps ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zimmerangebote - 2live 2gether</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--FÜR SVG-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        /*GOOGLE FONT*/
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap');
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#svg-object').ready(function(){
            var street = $('path').get();
            console.log(street);
        });

        function showStreet() {
            swal("Angebot-ID: 8426 PLZ: 20146 teilmöbliertes Zimmer, 23 m2 Frei ab: 01.01.2020 Nebenkosten: 40 Euro");
        }
    </script> 
</head>
```

console returns the following, no matter what I select: path , class or id.

[image]

Comment: the object tag display data of outer source. you cannot access it, same as you cannot access document inside an iframe

Comment: Why do you use `<object>` tag and don't place the `<svg>...</svg>` directly?

Comment: I ended up with this solution. my svg has like 10 paths, so it was a lot of code in my html document and I wanted 'outsource' it